# Does Git remove tag remove the underlying commits?

Tags: git

This is probably a very basic question, but can't figure it out.

If I remove a tag in my remote repository using:

git push --delete origin

Does that remove the underlying commit file changes associated to the tag? I just want to remove legacy tags that came from a repository imported from CVS/SVN. I want to keep my code, just without the tagging.

Thanks.

Comment: Normally, SVN tags never exist on trunk, because SVN tagging action is a commit.
Git tagging action is not a commit. It does not produce extra commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn’t, unless it’s not part of any other history. Tags point to specific commits; branches point to their tip commits; commits point to their parent commits. An object is only subject to garbage collection if nothing points to it at all.